# i and j equivalent in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I was wondering what the equivalent of "i" and "j" in C++ is in python. What I am trying to do is add each number in one set to the corresponding one in another (i.e. in the example below: [2+1], [4+3], [6+5]) I am trying to teach myself python off the internet, and I couldn't find how to do this. [example below doesn't work.]

```
even = [2,4,6]
odd = [1,3,5]
both = []
for i in range even[]:
    for j in range odd[]:
        if(i==j):
            both.append(even[i] + odd[j])
print(both)
```

I tried doing this:

```
for number1 in even:
    for number2 in odd:
        if(number1==number2):
            both.append(number + number2)
```

but this only performs addition if the numbers themselves are equal, which is not what I want. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `for i in range even[]` isn't valid syntax.  It would be `for i in range(len(even)):`, but this is highly "unpythonic".

Comment: @mgilson They pointed it out in the question that it was not valid.  I'm assuming it was intended to be pseudocode.

Comment: @SethMMorton -- Yes, I know.  I wanted to point out the correct python *syntax* even though it's not the best way to solve the problem.  For that, I left an answer below :)

Comment: I really hope you wouldn't be using two loops in C++, because that turns what should be an O(n) algorithm into O(n^2). You only need one index to iterate over both arrays at the same time.

Comment: @mgilson: got it to work it this way too. thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

The way you do this in python is with `zip`:

```
for number1, number2 in zip(even, odd):
    ...
```

Here's a complete example with a list comprehension:

```
both = [number1 + number2 for number1, number2 in zip(even, odd)]
```

I would guess that at least 90% of the time that you would use indices in a loop in other C-like languages, you can avoid it in python using the various builtins and/or the "for-each" nature of python's for loops.

Comment: @rafiki -- Sure, no problem.  Enjoy learning Python.  It's a blast!

Comment: @rafiki Saying "thanks" is best done on Stack Overflow by accepting a question.

Answer (score 1):

Why yours doesn't work:

In Python, you normally iterate over one list, tuple, whatever, and the iteration results are the contents, not the indexes.

If you need the indexes, you can iterate over `range(len(...))`, or you can do `for index, item in enumerate(l)`, but in most cases there are better ways, such as [the excellent answer by mgilson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20650906/296974).

Answer (score 0):

zip is a useful method.. another way to do your problem is to use map method.

```
z = [x for x in map(sum,zip(even,odd))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
even = [2,4,6]
odd = [1,3,5]
sum_1 =[]
# combine as single list using slice
both = even[0:]+odd[:3]
k=len(even)
m=len(odd)

# 1st method using zip
for i,j in zip(even,odd):
    print(i+j, end=" ")
print()
#2nd method using usual for loop
for i in range(0,k):
    if k==m:
        ele=both[i]+both[k+i]
        sum_1.append(ele)     #added element put into a list
        continue
    else:
        print("even and odd list length are not equal")
print(sum_1)
```